# To solve upside-down rendering?

Tags: c#, for-loop, console, nested, rendering

I have written this segment of C# to help me understand how nested for loops can be used to render 2 dimensional data.

Here is what the output looks like.

```
████
███
██
█
```

I would like to make it so that the 4 blocks up top are rendered at the bottom, basically in the reverse order so that the steps ascend.  However the console window only renders downward, so the conventional thinking won't be right.  The following is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write('\n');
            for (j = i; j < 4; j++) 
            {
                Console.Write("█");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is what I'd like the output to look like.

```
    █
   ██
  ███
 ████
```

Comment: All code executes in order.  To write the longest block at the top, you have to write it first.  There is no way to write it last but still have it at the top, unless you want to get into graphics rendering engines and point drawing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    const int Dimension = 4;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] blocks = new char[Dimension];
        for (int j = 0; j < Dimension; j++)
            blocks[j] = ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++)
        {
            blocks[Dimension - i - 1] = '█';

            for (int j = 0; j < Dimension; j++)
                Console.Write(blocks[j]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: PLUS ONE for steps Ascending ;P

Answer (score 4):

You need to *reverse* your loop condition from inremant to decremant..

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    Console.Write('\n');
    for (j = i; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        Console.Write("█");
    }
}
```

Output will be;

[image]

Here is a [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/RcmFbQ).

**UPDATE**: Since you change your mind, you need to add space every column (column number is`i`) `4 - 1` times.

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            {
                if ( j < 3 - i )
                    Console.Write(" ");
                else
                    Console.Write("█");
            }
            Console.Write('\n');
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image]

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/aBOgzK)**.

Comment: Soner, Thanks this points me in the direction I'd like to go, however these steps are descending,  I'd like them to go the other way.  I'm sorry if I did not make that clear.  I will take your idea and apply it to see how else it can be done!  thanks again!

Comment: @MonteEmerson Do you want asceding upstairs to the right side? Your question wasn't clear by the way.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm sorry, I revised it.

Comment: No I was having a joke with @Soner.  My answer does what you wanted - you have fiured it out youself though - you need to start by writing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
  for (j = 3 - i; j < 4; j++)
  {
       Console.Write("█");
  }
```

Comment: I think this would actually do 0,1,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,4? Simplest change though so the best answer if you edit that..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be: just reverse your inner loop condition and decrement the counter instead of incrementing it:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        Console.Write('\n');
        for (j = i; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            Console.Write("█");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

returning:

```
█
██
███
████
```

And for right-to-left version:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(j < 3 - i)
                Console.Write(" ");
            else
                Console.Write("█");
        }
        Console.Write('\n');
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

with a result:

```
   █
  ██
 ███
████
```

Comment: @Monte Emerson - see my answer